# I am using ubuntu 18.04.I got this error when i try to upgrade

Tags: 18.04

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-common all 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 [2,482 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-common all 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:20e50c1116271b6c38526a5d78e78c51b86bc48c7c03d0005ebe06a3e3fb23de
   - SHA1:01c39d0c31ccafba417891022bd61e6c32ae72a3 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:4e0888a7d1cf9a766599c554287910c1 [weak]
   - Filesize:2481700 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:af6b6c41ed8389b2aa5f672ede2c845baa5aa1eaeacec9de6ac34fac3fa53416
   - SHA1:2a769e00e6d76749e0f2b3d54975efa7d6b60701 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:6bfd90cbe01b7c3e5f666860f5bd73b2 [weak]
   - Filesize:2481700 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 17 May 2018 11:30:45 +0000
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-report amd64 1.2.0~bionic [1,694 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-report amd64 1.2.0~bionic
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:410b0572c1b66af9648c01bf66804c09986f00ed0843cf459a9d282c8d06402d
   - SHA1:e731d01aa7370cf5a8882949c04c081816792db9 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:153fa99051248ebfe7880ab9e04cc307 [weak]
   - Filesize:1693624 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:c7df99a8fdc7812a29ed79900c32fab6b371821f17e6463acbee9ac0f8684df5
   - SHA1:a57af71ecd4813d1a9190105d314248eac43f5b7 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3fb8028c3be9b1411cf21ceefef78d0d [weak]
   - Filesize:1693624 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 07:03:24 +0000
Fetched 4,175 kB in 6s (708 kB/s)          
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-software/gnome-software-common_3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:20e50c1116271b6c38526a5d78e78c51b86bc48c7c03d0005ebe06a3e3fb23de
    - SHA1:01c39d0c31ccafba417891022bd61e6c32ae72a3 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:4e0888a7d1cf9a766599c554287910c1 [weak]
    - Filesize:2481700 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:af6b6c41ed8389b2aa5f672ede2c845baa5aa1eaeacec9de6ac34fac3fa53416
    - SHA1:2a769e00e6d76749e0f2b3d54975efa7d6b60701 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6bfd90cbe01b7c3e5f666860f5bd73b2 [weak]
    - Filesize:2481700 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 17 May 2018 11:30:45 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-report/ubuntu-report_1.2.0~bionic_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:410b0572c1b66af9648c01bf66804c09986f00ed0843cf459a9d282c8d06402d
    - SHA1:e731d01aa7370cf5a8882949c04c081816792db9 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:153fa99051248ebfe7880ab9e04cc307 [weak]
    - Filesize:1693624 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:c7df99a8fdc7812a29ed79900c32fab6b371821f17e6463acbee9ac0f8684df5
    - SHA1:a57af71ecd4813d1a9190105d314248eac43f5b7 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:3fb8028c3be9b1411cf21ceefef78d0d [weak]
    - Filesize:1693624 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 03 Jul 2018 07:03:24 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Is your internet okay!

Comment: yes. my net working well

Answer (score 0):

I seem like your apt repository is not having some issue.

Please check `sources.list`  using the following command
`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

I this some url's were missed in that file.

Here I'm providing new `sources.list` file for ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Back up your old sources.list file and replace the contents in the in below link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DXVUaqi96hMuhecEMSinFVdyFwZWozbLOFu_-ZL_o08/edit

Now do `sudo apt-get update`
Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think that there is something wrong with sources.list

Comment: Sorry man not working

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a proxy, do the following

> sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf

Define a http: and a https: proxy

> Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
>
> Acquire::https::Proxy "https://user:password@proxy.server:port/";

Usually, there's no username when using a LAN-based proxy, so in that case you can just type the IP/hostname i.e

> "http://192.168.1.10:3128/";

and same for the https counterpart

> "https://192.168.1.10:3128/";

Run apt update to see if the error is gone.